# Re-render AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, templates, binding

I would expect such questions to be answered a million times but can not find anything that would work for my particular issue. My component looks like this:

```js
const todoApp = () => ({
  template: `
    <div>
      <todo-list todos="todoApp._filteredTodos"></todo-list>
    </div>
  `,
  controller: class {
    constructor(todoService) {
      [...]
    }

    updateState() {
      this._activeTodos = _.filter(this._todos, t => !t.completed);

      switch (this.selectedFilter) {
        case 'active':
          this._filteredTodos = _.filter(this._todos, t => !t.completed);
          break;
        case 'completed':
          this._filteredTodos = _.filter(this._todos, t => t.completed);
          break;
        default:
          this._filteredTodos = this._todos;
      }
    },

    updateTodos() {
      this._todos = this.todoService.fetch();
      this.updateState();
    }

    [...]
  },
  restrict: 'E',
  bindToController: true,
  controllerAs: 'todoApp',
  link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    document.addEventListener('store-update', ctrl.updateTodos.bind(ctrl), false);
  }
});

export default todoApp;
```

I need to update `todoApp._todos` so that `<todo-list>` gets updated with the new set of items. This doesn't happen atm.

The `<todo-list>` component is quite simple:

```
const todoList = () => ({
  scope: {
    todos: '=',
  },
  template: `
    <ul class="todo-list">
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos track by todo.id">
        [...]
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  controller: class {
    [...]
  },
  restrict: 'E',
  bindToController: true,
  controllerAs: 'todoList'
});

export default todoList;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What triggers the `updateState()` function?

Comment: That's a very good question, @georgeawg. I have updated the example with the call initiator - `updateTodos ()`. In its turn, `updateTodos()` is an event handler for a custom event.

Comment: How is the custom event integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle? Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: It's the simple `addEventListener` in component's `link` @georgeawg. I have updated the example. How more could I integrate that event into AngularJS execution context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
>     document.addEventListener('store-update', ctrl.updateTodos.bind(ctrl), false);
> }
> ```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

You can also use [`$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. **An explicit call to $apply is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks**, or when working with third-party library callbacks.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    document.addEventListener('store-update',storeUpdateHandler, false);
    scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        document.removeEventListener('store-update',storeUpdateHandler);
    });

    function storeUpdateHandler() {
        scope.$apply(ctrl.updateTodos.bind(ctrl));
    }
}
```

Also to avoid memory leaks, code should remove the event listener when the scope of the directive is destroyed.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation, @georgeawg. It works fine though throws `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress` from time to time. I have already played with `$apply` (just in the handler's function itself) and got it working, but your answer gives a better perspective on the problem.